# Firebase Authentication Sign in Providers Not Enabling

Tags: authentication, firebase

I'm getting started with Firebase and I want to enable one of the authentication services, but the little slider won't turn on.

I'm assuming maybe I'm missing some information but it doesn't tell me anything.

They just recently revamped their entire setup... anyone else struggling to enable any of these?

Comment: Very odd! What authentication method was it (or all of them)? What browser are you on, and are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Success. The slider UI component only works as a button. I was dragging it repeatedly and it wouldn't snap on. Probably a bug. Funny.